# Enable/Disable Wi-Fi communication on a mobile device when entering or exiting a fixed location like an industrial space

Tags: mobile, geolocation, gps, wifi, geofencing

I have a client that has an industrial space. In this space they have automated machines that move up/down, sideways, forward/backward, and raise completely by swinging the machine’s bottom upward.  To control these devices they have a large system box with relays that basically tell which switch to activate.  This control box is in the center of the industrial space.  What they want is to store all the logic and system files in the “control center” box (that is located in the middle of the space) and then have the ability to operate individuals machines, or several machines either, all together or synchronously, while personally moving around the space.   After talking with them, they are keen to the idea of us developing a Wi-Fi based interface in the Control Center, and then be able to use a mobile device (phone or tablet) to communicate with it.  The Wi-Fi and mobile app concept is easy enough to write, the issue is that they have two concerns: Personal Safety, and Security of the network.

For personal safety, they need it to be that the mobile device cannot connect or operate the equipment if the user is NOT in the same room, or space.  Meaning, they cannot push a button on the tablet, walk away or out of sight and not see if a machine is crushing an employee, or an employee is not playing around and dangling from the equipment. So they have to actually be within eye sight in order to watch for safety.

For security, they want to be able to connect to the Control Center through Wi-Fi, and operate the system. They do not want other people with smart devices or laptops to be able to access, hack it, and see the addresses and so on.

I was originally thinking of using GPS satellites and establish GeoPolygon (GeoFence), using latitudes and longitudes, to map out the perimeter of the industrial space. Then with that, when the user enters or exits the space the GPS would trigger a push notification (like a foursquare check-in), and disable/enable Wi-Fi connections, and thus  letting the user know that Wi-Fi is either on or off and they can or cannot access the control center to operate the machines.

The problem I found is that GPS can be unreliable, especially indoors, in cityscapes, or when there is a lot of frequency static or interference.

So, to finish my long story, I was wondering if anyone had any plausible ideas as to how I can toggle Wi-Fi access on or off based on the user’s location and when the user is moving in or out of the fixed-location space (ie. wharehouse)?

Comment: What is the maximum error in distance acceptable for the device poition vs real position in order to enable / disable the connection to the controll center?

Comment: Well, Alex, that is a good question. I would say the maximum error distance is within 18 inches (45.72cm). Basically if someone were to take the mobile device outside, I would not want them to be able to control machinery on the other side of the wall.  They could be standing right next to the control center, outside, and I would not want them to be able to access it.

Comment: @JoshC Cool question. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

GPS does not provide 18 inches of accuracy.
Indoors, GPS probably does not work at all, or with errors of 30m or more.

Outside 3- 6 m is normal, in cities up to 30m error happend evry day, too (in a 20 minute trip driving home, passing by houses with height of 18m left and right of the road.)

Wifi also works for higher distances, you cannot get the distance to the device.

What you probably need is another thing:

**NFC**: Near Field Communication
Till the current Iphone 5, NFC is not supported.
Maybe next generations or some Android phones.

At least you now know what does not work.

Comment: I know GPS wont work because of unreliability and distance error.  WIFI in our setup has multiple access point and does allow automation of equipment from anywhere in the building instantaneously.  NFC wont work for my application because it relies on the operator to physically touch or be "right on top of" the tag.  I use NFC stamps with my Samsung phone. Neat but not practical for my purposes. I would like wi-fi communications to be disabled immediately when a user exits a location. Any ideas?

Comment: Disabled when exits by more than 18 inches, or when leaving the factory?

Comment: Further you cannot force the device to disable Wifi, that does not work!

Comment: Disabled (turned off) when stepping through the exit doors of the factory. And as for forcing the mobile device to disable wifi i disagree. I have an app that once i get out of my set radius away from my center point, wifi  is disabled (turned off). then again enabled (turned on) when i am back within the radius.

Comment: @JoshC ok the app can of course disable its own connection, but not wifi at all.

Comment: blueTooth operates only on short distance, you could think of that too

Answer (score 0):

I heard about wallpaper made for blocking wifi connection, maybe you can put this wallpaper inside the rooms and make more networks, so only person inside the room can control this room, than connect that wifi modem with cabel to some network controll PC and throught it you can control remotely also that room.